# TypeScript minified breaks Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an MVC application with lots of Angular code. I have an Angular service that creates an Angular UI modal. The pertinent code is:

```
export class ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalService {

    static $inject = ["$uibModal"];
    constructor(private $uibModal: any) {
    }

    public open(options: LargeResultSetModalOptions): ng.IPromise<LargeResultsModalAction> {
        var modalInstance = this.$uibModal.open(
            {
                templateUrl: "myTemplate.html",
                controller: "ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController",
                controllerAs: "confirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController",
                backdrop: "static",
                resolve: {
                    modalOptions: () => options
                }
            });

        return modalInstance.result.then((action: LargeResultsModalAction) => {
            return action;
        });
    }
}

angular.module("My.Module").service("Services.ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalService", Services.ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalService);
```

The controller (snippet) is:

```
export class ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController {
    public confirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController: ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController = this;

    //static $inject = ["$uibModalInstance"];
    constructor(private $uibModalInstance: any, private modalOptions: LargeResultSetModalOptions) {

    }

    public ok(): void {
        this.$uibModalInstance.close(LargeResultsModalAction.Continue);
    }

    // more methods not shown
}

angular.module("My.Module").controller("Services.ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController", Services.ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController);
```

Now, in my dev env, this works fine. The modal pops up, the controller has the $uibModalInstance and modalOptions parameters correctly injected. In Production, with bundling enabled, it breaks - in that nothing happens at all. No console error either.

If I uncomment the static inject line on the controller, then it breaks in dev and in Production the modal pops up but doesn't work correctly because presumably it's not the modal instance instantiated by the service as the modalOptions parameter remains undefined.

My question is, how can I minify this code and still have the correct instance of $uibModalInstance injected? Hopefully I'm missing something very simple and all the hair that has been pulled today has been a mere exercise in frustration.

Comment: Are you using the service in the controller? I'm not seeing it getting injected. I'm wondering why you even need `$uibModalInstance` in the controller at all.

Comment: In your $inject I see that you're only passing '$uibModalInstance' but not modalOptions. Don't you need both?

Comment: Yes, I only included the constructor. There are methods on the controller such as:         public ok(): void {
            this.$uibModalInstance.close(LargeResultsModalAction.Continue);
        }

Comment: How are you actually declaring your controller/service instances? I can't see that in your code examples. You should look into declaring them using "safe" or "inline" annotations -- this will prevent potential errors from minification. If you're using a task-runner like Grunt/Gulp, look into the `ng-annotate` library. It will save you tons of trouble: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: @Mickers - the modalOptions parameter is injected by the resolve part of the uibModal config.

Comment: I've updated the code snippets with the registration in Angular. @BenBeck, the minification is done by standard MVC bundling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use what is known as safe or inline dependency injection annotation.

For example in your controller:

```
angular.module("My.Module")
    .controller("Services.ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController", ["uibModalInstance", "modalOptions", Services.ConfirmRenderingOfLargeResultsModalController]);
```

This will preserve the dependency names when you minify your code.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that worked a treat. We used to use this method of injection but migrated to static inject but I guess there's a reason why the inline method is the preferred one according to the docs.

Comment: The static inject method is nice because you only really have to declare it once as opposed to this method where you declare all your dependencies twice. But, I've always found that this is the best method for preserving dependency names during code minification.